# Converting REXP object to a double array (Java/R)

Tags: java, r, jri

I want R to produce, for example, normal data and then use this data in Java. I know there is a function to convert an REXP object to an array but it doesn't seem to work. Here is what I have:

```
REXP x;
x = re.eval("rnorm(100,50,10)");
double[] test = x.asDoubleArray();
System.out.println(x);
System.out.println(test);
```

I have printed both out to see what is wrong. The results are as follows:

```
[REAL* (61.739814266023316, 40.25177570831545, 36.09450830843867, 48.06821029847672,...etc)]
[D@61de33
```

The problem is how R returns the results to java; it tells java what x is, if they were strings it would say [String*(..whatever..)]. I just want what is in the bracket. Also the line it returns is a string regardless.

I will be working with large data so I want it to be fast. I had tried to use subsets, extracting what is in the brackets and then parsing them to doubles but there must be a better solution. Also that doesn't seem to work for data with more than 100 points.

Comment: Sorry ignore this.......not paying attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's already a reference to this question, let here be an answer:

`System.out.println(test);` where `test` is `double[]` literally means `System.out.println(test.toString());`

The problem is, in Java, arrays have got a very poor implementation of `toString()`. Hence, in order to get the result you need, you need to use

```
REXP x;
x = re.eval("rnorm(100,50,10)");
double[] test = x.asDoubleArray();
System.out.println(x);
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(test)); // note we get an array-backed list here
```

as lists have proper `toString()` method.

Again, my apologies for an obvious answer.