# Call R from Java using JRI, how to cast return value

Tags: java, r, jri, rjava

I'm executing some R commands from Java using JRI.I want to use the results from R in my Java for further calculations but I have no idea how cast the returned object.

### call code in Java:

```
REXP x;
System.out.println(x = rengine.eval("source(\"/..../TS.R\")"));
System.out.println( x.asVector().elementAt(0));
```

---

### last line from R code:

```
eq_all[length(eq_all)-1]
```

--

### output in Java console:

```
[VECTOR ([REAL* (3.050462038715372)], [BOOLi* ])]
[REAL* (3.050462038715372)]
```

---

"3.050462038715372" is the right value but how can I access it in Java?

best regards,
Immanuel

PS. related question without answer:
[Converting REXP object to a double array (Java/R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471689/converting-rexp-object-to-a-double-array-java-r)

Answer (score 0):

I believe [`asDouble()`](http://www.rosuda.org/r/nightly/javadoc/org/rosuda/JRI/REXP.html#asDouble()) and [`asDoubleArray()`](http://www.rosuda.org/r/nightly/javadoc/org/rosuda/JRI/REXP.html#asDoubleArray()) are what you need.

**Update:** So on your code example, it should be:

```
REXP x;
System.out.println(x = rengine.eval("source(\"/..../TS.R\")"));
System.out.println(x.asVector().elementAt(0).asDouble());
```

PS. The referred question actually had the answer you needed—the problem there is with implementation of `toString()` in Java arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the input but I already tried that '       System.out.println( x.asDouble());
       System.out.println( x.asDoubleArray());' gives me '0.0' and
'null'

Comment: I've got no `"source(\"/..../TS.R\")"`—hence cannot check your code. Could you give a http://sscce.org/ please?

Comment: `x.asDouble())` would not work, since x is not a scalar. See the update.

Comment: I need to think over it again, sscce is not so easy because of dependencies. I have a feeling that my R data type could be the problem.

Comment: Check the update first; it well may be you have no problem yet :)

Comment: Figured it out :D. Running the R code using `"source(...)"` was the problem it returns `"[VECTOR ([REAL* (3.050462038715372)], [BOOLi* ])]"` instead of `"[REAL* (3.050462038715372)]"`. A separate call to get the results (using your answer) solved the problem. Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

elementAt() is not working, your could use at().

```
REXP x;
System.out.println(x = rengine.eval("source(\"/..../TS.R\")"));
System.out.println(x.asVector().at(0).asDouble());
```